# Oracle - Convert and display sysdate in EST

Tags: oracle11g

Using oracle 11 , how to Convert and display sysdate in EST?
Server is in PST location

I tried this:

```
select from_tz(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP),'EST') from dual
/
```

I don't get correct results..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `systimestamp` since that includes a time zone.

```
select systimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern'
  from dual;
```

should return a timestamp in the Eastern time zone (assuming your database time zone files are up to date).

Note that if you ask for a timestamp in EST, that should be an hour earlier than the current time in the Eastern time zone of the United States because the US is in Daylight Savings Time.  So the Eastern time zone is in EDT currently not EST.

Comment: You can certainly wrap a `to_char` around the expression if you want to convert the `timestamp` to a `varchar2`.  Or you can set your sessions `nls_timestamp_format` if your application uses that as the default method for converting timestamps to strings for display.

Answer (score 2):

Use `systimestamp` rather than `sysdate`, because it is already timezone-aware; then `at time zone` to translate:

```
select systimestamp at time zone 'America/New_York' from dual
```

Using a region is better/safer than an abbreviation like 'EST", which might not be unique; and [gives you the wrong answer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8792c9f5fb967821b6c1406e8baca6d3) - this shows mine, Justin's alternative (and maybe better!) region, what you get with EST, and all the things EST is an abbreviation of. (You could use `EST5EDT`, but a region is still clearer.)

You could also set your session to an East-coat region (if it isn't already) and then use `current_timestamp` instead of `systimestamp`:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';
select current_timestamp from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3f5b5a55fe5f1f5a1ff50d1ad3213ab)

Either way, how it is displayed is down to your client/application - e.g. the session `nls_timestamp_tz_format` - unless you convert it to a string with `to_char()`, supplying the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `SYSDATE` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT from_tz(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP),'PST') AT TIME ZONE 'EST5EDT' FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP),'PST')ATTIMEZONE'EST5EDT' |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 02-APR-21 11.07.33.000000 PM EST5EDT                       |
> ```

or:

```sql
SELECT from_tz(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP),'US/Pacific') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP),'US/PACIFIC')ATTIMEZONE'US/EASTERN' |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 02-APR-21 11.07.33.000000 PM US/EASTERN                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5f2a83874b278412b0596443eb29d4c)*